# Cómo obtener el https de mi url?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, razor

Tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Tengo un método que obtiene la url, pero lo trae con http y mi url es https.

Aquí muestro mi código que obtengo mi url base.

```
@{
        String base_url = HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(
            new Uri(
                new Uri(this.Context.Request.Url.Scheme+"://"+this.Context.Request.Url.Host),

                Url.Content("~/")
            ).ToString());
        if (base_url == "/")
        {
            base_url = "";
        }
    }
```

Este es mi url
https://app.miweb.com/SeguimientoDS

Lo que obtengo con mi método
http://app.miweb.com/SeguimientoDS

No se porque no puede obtener el https ya que devuelve http.

Comment: si a veces causa problema pero puedes agregarle https usando la funcion en un if Request.IsSecureConnection  , con esto sabemos que es https

Comment: Si pero la condición va a devolver false y no podría agregar la "s"

Comment: Revisa las propidedades del request que es cuando se  establece la comunicacion porque en caso de  que el servidor ofrezca ambas comunicaciones te puede seguir mostrando hppt, ejemplo revisa var rootUrl= request.IsHttps ? "https" : "http";

Comment: No entiendo que estas queriendo lograr, porque necesitas armar de esta forma un url ? no tiene ningun sentido. Para que usas esa base_url ? porque creo que estas equivocando el camino

Comment: La url la voy a empezar a llamar en todos mi archivos js que usan ajax para tener la url base.